# scikit-learn load_mlcomp exception "Could not find dataset with metadata line: name: 20news-18828"

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying some simple examples on a book.

But somehow it makes an error.

```
import sklearn.datasets
MLCOMP_DIR = r"~/my/data/"
data = sklearn.datasets.load_mlcomp("20news-18828", mlcomp_root=MLCOMP_DIR)

ValueError: Could not find dataset with metadata line: name: 20news-18828
```

Comment: 20news can also be downloaded with `fetch_20newsgroups`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this function to work, with the path you specified you need to make sure you download the 379 dataset and extract it into the folder ~/my/data.

The problem is probably because of your file structure.

Make sure you have the folder ~/my/data/379 and in it should be the metadata file along with the folders test, train and raw.

Answer (score 1):

Have you followed the instructions in the example?
From the file

```
 The dataset used in this example is the 20 newsgroups dataset and should be
 downloaded from the http://mlcomp.org (free registration required):

  http://mlcomp.org/datasets/379
```

I am not sure what you mean by "on a book". This function is for extracting this specific dataset.

Answer (score 1):

At first you should extract the zip file, dataset-379-20news-18828_WJQIG.zip (or a similar file that can be found in http://mlcomp.org/datasets/379#). After unzipping the file you get folder 379 which contains raw, train, test, and a metadata file.

To work with:

data = sklearn.datasets.load_mlcomp("20news-18828", 'train', mlcomp_root=MLCOMP_DIR)

you should set MLCOMP_DIR as, for example, "D:\data\ML" while folder 379 is inside ML folder.

So, MLCOMP_DIR should be "D:\data\ML", not "D:\data\ML\379" .